# How to use curry function

Tags: scala

I have a curried function on the object:

```
sealed trait Sum[A, B]

final case class Left[A, B](value: A) extends Sum[A, B]

final case class Right[A, B](value: B) extends Sum[A, B]

object Sum {

  def fold[A, B, C](s: Sum[A, B])(left: A => C)(right: B => C): C =
    s match {
      case Left(v) => left(v)
      case Right(v) => right(v)
    }

}
```

How to use the fold function? I tried as follow:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val l = Sum.fold(Left(5))(l => l * l)

  }
}
```

But I do not know, how to pass the third argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an do it like:

```
  val a: Sum[Int, Int] = Left(5)
  val l = Sum.fold(a)(l => l * l)(l => l * l)
```

OR

```
  val l = Sum.fold(Left[Int, Int](5))(l => l * l)(l => l * l)
```

You need to both specify `Sum`'s `A` and `B` type for compiler can infer `Left` and `Right` `A` and `B` type.

As your code snippet, you only has specify the `Left` `A` type to `Int` without `B` type, the compiler can't infer `B` type, so for your third **high-order** function parameter, In **compile time**, the compiler will fail in here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give an explicit type to  B for the `right` function:

```
 val l = Sum.fold(Left(5))(a => a * a)((b: Int) => b * b)
```